# Who makes the arrows in TV show Arrow?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrow, arrowverse

[Arrow](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2193021/)

I was searching for the source of arrows but had no luck. In S01 there were some mentions that Oliver Queen made arrows for himself. I think I saw some scenes too of making arrows by Oliver himself (normal ones). But then we saw some custom arrows, arrows with explosives and sound recorder/transmitter.

Now where did these arrows come from?

[image]

These require technical skill that Oliver didn't have. He is a drop out. So he can't make cool stuff like Iron man can all by himself. In the beginning of S02 there was a mention that the bow was custom made and was a gift from Felicity. But there wasn't any mention about arrows. And I don't think Felicity made them, there also weren't any scenes of making those arrows (upto S03E02 that I've seen).

There is an option: Queen Consolidated's Applied Science division. But there are 2 problems:

1. His arrows' carry unique signatures.

   In S01 Detective Lance identified that signature and differentiated which one is Arrow's arrow and which one is from copycat Arrow (Merlyn). For this same reason Queen consolidated staff can know who is Arrow, the person that ordered to make them.
2. In S02 ending portion Oliver lost the company, so he can't use its resources. But we saw in the beginning of S03 that he still got plenty of arrows. So I guess it's not Oliver's company that makes them.

[image]

Iron man made his toys by himself, Batman created some by himself and others are made by Lucius, Flash gets his stuff from Star Labs. So how is Oliver getting these huge amounts of arrows, especially custom made ones? Any source where it's explained?

Comment: " He is a drop out." doesn't means he can't.

Comment: yeah true, doesn't mean he can't but it's not shown either that he has the expertise or the skill @AnkitSharma

Comment: I feel its implicit Oliver Queen is a billionaire with resources to have a proxy company make it out for him.

Comment: could be, I was looking for something official from the makers.Or at least  logical explanation. As it's very easy to identify Arrow by the arrows if the source is unreliable. @Dredd

Comment: As a logical point, I doubt Ollie gets his arrows made on demand. Like batman, he has a bulk order of parts made, then he assembles them. He has stock piles of spare arrows, so even when he lost Queen Consolidated, he still had arrows around. And that's pretty similar to his older comic history.

Comment: @cde I like your idea. He can order in parts and assemble himself. So he doesn't need the technical knowledge to build them.

Comment: Maybe he has a 3D printer tucked away somewhere. It's not hard to take the casing off a small recording device, and put the device's guts in a custom case that can be attached to an arrow.

Answer (score 8):

### Oliver gets them from an inventor named Lodai

In the canon comic series *Arrow: Season 2.5*, Chapter 3: "[Acolyte](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Acolyte)", Diggle visits Lodai (whom he has clearly worked with before) and gives him money in exchange for a case of arrows, including trick arrows. He also is hired to develop a new suit for Arsenal (Roy Harper) and is told to make it kevlar-lined "just like the other one".

While it's not explicitly stated that Lodai made the arrows himself, the fact that he can "make anything" suggests that he did.

[image]
[image: Lodai, Arrow Season 2.5]

Comment: And as a note to anyone, Season 2.5 is considered canon by DC and by the show producers, with some characters introduced in the comic showing up in season 3. While Lodai hasn't, unless there is a contradiction in the show, this is ***100% canon answer***.

Answer (score 0):

He made himself. Need of survival of 5 years in an Island had thought him so many things. I have not read or seen any other sources explaining this except couple of episodes in season 1 showing how he started learning shooting arrows from Yao Fe and Shado where they never showed anything about making arrows (not even their trainers)

Comment: While I agree this is the case, could you please show some documentation that proves it to be so? As the OP posted in a comment "I was looking for something official from the makers."

Comment: He doesn't have any college degree nor the training to attach mini remote controlled / automatic bombs with arrows.

Comment: Of course you don't need a degree to know how to use electronics, or off the shelf explosive arrows.

Comment: @cde  What store has those shelves off which a consumer can purchase explosive arrows?

Comment: "*you don't need a degree to know how to use electronics, or off the shelf explosive arrows*"  What you need is a one wrong guy who can teach you these things and the access to black market for the raw materials for its development

Answer (score 0):

Oliver has said multiple times that he is good with electronics, as his dad had a plane and he used to to help fix it, this explains where some of the early arrows come from.

Answer (score -2):

He gets his arrows from Argus. The only organization that knows who he is and has multiple resources for the arrows he needs. Amanda W. was always his ally and then Lila became the new director who is apart of team arrow

Comment: I think he had special arrows even before Argus showed up. I don't watch the show much so I may be wrong

Comment: While it would make sense for Argus to give him arrows, there is unfortunately no evidence that this occurs on the show and it is just speculation. Plus as cde noted, Oliver was not in contact with Argus when he first started using the arrows.